# no git found when installing react plugin for Atom

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor

I am using Windows 10 but installing react jsx plugin for atom fails. I have already installed git. But error says it cant find git. I even went to system variables and added to path

> C:\Users\dove\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin

because its where my git is installed. What could be the problem?

This is the error in details

> Installing “react@0.16.2” failed.Hide output… Failed to install react
>   because Git was not found.
>
> The react package has module dependencies that cannot be installed
>   without Git.
>
> You need to install Git and add it to your path environment variable
>   in order to install this package.
>
> You can install Git by downloading, installing, and launching GitHub
>   for Windows: https://windows.github.com
>
> Run apm -v after installing Git to see what version has been detected.

Comment: Just to make this clear, you're installing Atom package [`react`](https://atom.io/packages/react), correct? Why do you need Git for that?

Comment: I also didnt know i needed git but thats the error it gives. It says some of the componets of the plugin need git. and git is not found

Comment: If you have Atom in your `PATH`, type in the following command in a terminal: `$ apm install react`

Comment: on windows in cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command in a terminal or Git Bash:

```
$ apm install react
```

or

```
$ apm install react@0.16.2
```

`0.16.2` being the latest version as of 2017-08-02.

If this fails, you can resort to configuring Git to use the `git` protocol instead of `http` by typing:

```
$ git config --global url.git://github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
```